# When have you used dynamic programming in the field?

Tags: language-agnostic, optimization, field, dynamic-programming

When have you ever directly applied the concepts of [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) to solve a problem in the field? It's sometimes not evident how it can be applied when using it to solve a made-up instance of the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a lot more common to use [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to solve problems in the field, since it's applicable to a wider set of problems.  DP is really only called for when you have a lot of overlapping sub-problems, like in calculating fibonacci numbers (the hard way), or prime numbers (the efficient way).

Incidentally, the page you linked to has a [list of algorithms that use DP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Algorithms_that_use_dynamic_programming).